How to preserve Sticky activation with React.JS
I've come into such a problem:

user click 'open' button
videoplayer's opened
videoplayer can't autoplay due to browser restriction policy.

I've logged navigator.userActivation.hasBeenActive and it shows me 'false', but in some cases of videoplayer usage I get 'true'
I'm using React and when user clicks button I do event.persist() so that it can't be pooled.
Maybe I'm doing something wrong and there's more that should be taken into account?
I encounter that behaviour when only using Chrome, all other browsers work good

Chrome enforces stricter autoplay policies than other browsers. By default, video with audio won't autoplay unless certain user interactions have occurred (like clicking a button). Chrome allows autoplay if the video starts muted. You can initially mute the video and then allow the user to unmute it if desired. You can do something like following:

use a useState hook to manage the mute state (muted). Initially, keep
the video muted (muted={true}).
Clicking the "Open Video" button plays the video in a mute state (video.play()).
Add a "Unmute/Mute" button that toggles the muted state.


It's just not desired behaviour...for example when you open Youtube video it's automatically playing with sound. The problem's I don't understand why exactly my  userActivation is neglected

navigator.userActivation.hasBeenActive indicates if the user has recently interacted with the page. It cannot override Chrome's autoplay policy.
